# swift segue from collectionviewcell to a new view causes break when cell is clicked

Tags: ios, swift, segue, uicollectionviewcell

When i click on the cell during run time the program seems to break and i get this :
`EXC_BREAKPOINT(code=EXC_I386_BPT,subcode=0x0`

I didn't have this problem up until the point i created a segue from the `collectionviewcell` to a new view controller.

here's my code for the main view controller and to the view controller it's going to :

main view controller :

```
class FlashViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

@IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!

var decks: [Deck] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Move on ...
    let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 75, left: 20, bottom: 10, right: 20)
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 150, height: 200)
    collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    self.collectionView.dataSource = self
    self.collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.registerClass(DeckCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "DeckCollectionViewCell")
    collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.view.addSubview(collectionView!)

    var deck1 = Deck()
    deck1.name = "SAT is the bomb"
    self.decks.append(deck1)

}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.decks.count
}


func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    var deck = self.decks[indexPath.row]
    var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("DeckCollectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as DeckCollectionViewCell
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    cell.textLabel?.text = deck.name
    cell.textLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "circle")
    return cell
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("decksToCardsSegue", sender: self)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var nextViewController = segue.destinationViewController as NewDeckViewController
    nextViewController.deckCollection = self
}
}
```

new view controller :

```
class DeckViewController : UIViewController{

     override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         // Move on ...
     }
}
```

Comment: One thing i forgot to mention. I do also have another segue from the same main view controller to another different view controller. but that segue only happens when a bar item is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your Storyboard Segue identifier is "decksToCardsSegue", check your Segue and Segue Class under your identifier and make sure they are correct.